# Woocommerce redirect users after add to cart for certain categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using this website https://jeroensormani.com/redirect-users-after-add-to-cart/ and the section Redirect for certain categories I have adapted the below code to redirect the customer to another category page instead of the cart after they click on the product Add to cart button. If I put a product in more than one category however when it's added to the cart it defaults to the first category URL. You can not have a product in more than one category with different category redirect URL's. Is there a way to get it to recognise the category the customer is viewing not just the first category the product is in and redirect the customer according to the category they added the product from?

```html
        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || ! is_numeric( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
            return $url;
        }
   
        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) );
   
        // Only redirect products that have the 't-shirts' category
        if ( has_term( 't-shirts', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
       
        return $url = "http://mywebsite.com/shop/hats/";
        }

        // Only redirect products that have the 'hats' category
        if ( has_term( 'hats', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
   
        return $url = "http://mywebsite.com/shop/bags/";
        }

        // Only redirect products that have the 'bags' category
        if ( has_term( 'bags', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
   
        return $url = "http://mywebsite.com/shop/socks";
        }
   
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

I tried using the below code from [custom add to cart redirection for a defined product category in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260883/custom-add-to-cart-redirection-for-a-defined-product-category-in-woocommerce-3) as recommended by another user but it only works for the first category. The following categories default to the first category link.

```html
// REPLACING ADD TO CART BUTTON LINK ON SHOP AND ARCHIVES

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable-subscription' ) || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return $button;

    $button_text = __( 'View product', 'woocommerce' );
    $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    return $button;
}

// THE CUSTOM CONDITIONAL REDIRECTION

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'add_to_cart_checkout_redirection', 99, 1 );
function add_to_cart_checkout_redirection( $url ) {

    // HERE define your category
    $category = 't-shirts';

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) return $url;

    // Get the product id when it's available (on add to cart click)
    $product_id = absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );

    // Checkout redirection url only for your defined product category
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        // Clear add to cart notice (with the cart link).
        wc_clear_notices();
        $url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    }

    return $url = "http://mywebsite.com/shop/hats/";



    // HERE define your category
    $category = 'hats';

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) return $url;

    // Get the product id when it's available (on add to cart click)
    $product_id = absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );

    // Checkout redirection url only for your defined product category
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        // Clear add to cart notice (with the cart link).
        wc_clear_notices();
        $url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    }

    return $url = "http://mywebsite.com/shop/bags/";



    // HERE define your category
    $category = 'bags';

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) return $url;

    // Get the product id when it's available (on add to cart click)
    $product_id = absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );

    // Checkout redirection url only for your defined product category
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
        // Clear add to cart notice (with the cart link).
        wc_clear_notices();
        $url = wc_get_checkout_url();
    }

    return $url = "http://mywebsite.com/shop/socks";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom add to cart redirection for a defined product category in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260883/custom-add-to-cart-redirection-for-a-defined-product-category-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it did not work. I have edited my question above to show the test I did with that code.