# Woocommerec add to cart redirection with a Query String

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to do the following;
If the product has the  query string ?redirect-cart

1. redirect to checkout when clicking "add to cart"
2. Add a new  query string ?hide-custom-fields
3. [Apply CSS to a Page URL That Contains “string”](https://www.businessbloomer.com/wordpress-add-css-specific-page-url-via-php/)

I'm working from:
[Clear WooCommerce Cart with a Query String and Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46260934/8360353) and
[custom add to cart redirection for a defined product category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46260934/8360353)

This is what I have: [UPDATED]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'add_to_cart_checkout_redirection', 99, 1 );
function add_to_cart_checkout_redirection( $url ) {
    // If the URL contains redirect_cart
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  
if ( false !== strpos( $url, 'redirect-cart' ) ) {

        // Clear add to cart notice (with the cart link).
        wc_clear_notices();
        $url = wc_get_checkout_url().'?hide-custom-fields';
   }
    return $url;
}
```

is not working.

Comment: yes. However I can make  isset( $_GET['redirect-cart'] ) work with other functions e.g. empty cart. without any problems.

Comment: I have updated the question with another method of getting the URL.

Comment: no, it does not.

Comment: I'm gonna go with replacing the button instead - with a custom one, going straight to checkout.